# Wine barrels covered in animal fat

Tags: halacha, grapes-wine, shulchan-aruch, rama

In [Yoreh Deah siman 121](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.121.1) when talking about hecksher kelim, the Rema says:

> הַגָּה: יֵשׁ מְקוֹמוֹת שֶׁנָּהֲגוּ הֶתֵּר לָשׂוּם יַיִן בְּכֵלִים שֶׁנִּסְרֵיהֶם מְדֻבָּקִים בְּחֵלֶב, מִשּׁוּם שֶׁטֶּבַע הַיַּיִן לִבְרֹחַ מִן הַחֵלֶב, וְהַחֵלֶב נִקְרָשׁ וְעוֹמֵד בְּעַצְמוֹ וְאֵינוֹ נוֹגֵעַ כְּלָל בַּיַּיִן.

What is this animal fat based glue that people are smearing inside wine jugs, and why were they doing it?

Comment: Maybe something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_glue or alternatively like http://www.grapeandgranary.com/barrel-sealing-wax-4-3-oz-block.html

Comment: Waterproofing the jugs?